# How to connect the services inside docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

This is my docker-compose file, I cannot connect to the database

```yml
version: "3.9"
services:
  mongodb:
    image: mongo:5.0.2
    container_name: armaghan_db
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - armaghan-network
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    volumes:
      - db:/data/db
  backend:
    container_name: armaghan_backend
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: "Dockerfile"
    ports:
      - "5001:5000"
    networks:
      - armaghan-network
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      PORT: 5000
      armaghan_jwtPrivateKey: privatekeyarmaghansoroushmadani
      armaghan_db: mongodb://localhost:27017/armaghan
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
volumes:
  db:
networks:
  armaghan-network:
    driver: bridge
```

the mongodb image is running, I can make a connection to it when I run the application without docker. but connection fails inside docker.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiple Mongo Container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73415151/multiple-mongo-container)

Comment: @HoàngHuyKhánh No, I am trying to connect to mongodb://localhost:27017/armaghan which is available outside the container, but not inside.

Comment: Right, in Docker `localhost` usually means "the current container", so you're telling the `backend` container to connect to itself.  [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) in the Docker documentation might be a good starting point.

Comment: The connection should be `mongodb://armaghan_db:27017/armaghan`. Tell me if it work!

Comment: @yesper I'm on another project now, I will check it and accept your answer if it works. thank you ♥️

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to other services in the same network by their **service name**, see [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) for an example. Therefore instead of localhost, call the database by *mongodb://**mongodb**:27017/armaghan*